# How to redirect to a new view with data in MVC5?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

In my _Layout.cshml file, I have the following code segment:

```
<div class="input-top">
    <a class="GoBtn" href=""><img src="~/Content/img/GOBtn.png" class="gobtn-position"></a>
    <input id="homeZipCode" type="text" class="form-control input-position-2" placeholder="ZIP">
    <input id="homeService" type="text" class="form-control input-position-1" placeholder="What do you need done today?">
</div>
```

And the point is that I want to get the value of the two input fields above, and redirect to a new view when the href attribute is clicked, but when it redirects and opens the new view, in the new view, in the specific two input fields instead of blanks, I want those data to be presented, I mean those text to be written. In the view that I redirect, I have something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ZipCode, "Zip", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceName, "Service", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ServiceName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "service-manual" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

For this reason, I tried to write an AJAX call, and put it in my _Layout.cshtml file, but it doesn't seem to work. Below you can find my AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.GoBtn').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var homeZipCode = $("#homeZipCode").val();
        var homeService = $("#homeService").val();

        var model = { StateID: 1, ZipCode: homeZipCode, ServiceName: homeService };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ServiceRequest", "Home")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: JSON.stringify(model)
        })
            .success(function (result) {
            });
    });
});
```

The problem is that, when I click the href attribute, the view is not redirected, I'm still at the view that I clicked href. What can be the problem?

EDIT:

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a state")]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public int StateID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a zip code")]
    [Display(Name = "Zip")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose a service")]
    [Display(Name = "Service")]
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
 }
```

And my controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ServiceRequest()
    {
        ViewBag.StateID = new SelectList(db.States, "StateID", "StateName");
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ServiceRequest(RequestViewModel rvm, HttpPostedFileBase image = null, HttpPostedFileBase video = null)
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `e.preventDefault();` inside your click event which is preventing the default behaviour of click on a link.

And for your use case, You do not need to use ajax posting. You can put your input controls inside a form tag and keep a submit button. If you still want the link, instead of submit button, you can write a little javascript to post the form when user clicks on your link button.

And in the server side, have an action method which accepts your form content, then redirect to a new view. You can create a viewmodel and set the properties of that and send that to your new view.

```
@using(Html.Beginform("Service","Home"))
{
  <div class="input-top">
    <a class="GoBtn" href=""><img src="~/Content/img/GOBtn.png"></a>
    <input name="ZipCode" type="text" class="form-control input-position-2" >
    <input name="HomeService" type="text" class="form-control input-position-1" >
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
  </div>
}
```

and your server side code will be

```
public ActionResult Service(ServiceRequestViewModel model)
{
  return View(model);
}
```

Assuming that you have View model like this

```
public class ServiceRequestViewModel 
{
  public string ZipCode {set;get;}
  public string HomeService{set;get;}
}
```

And now your second view, `service.cshtm`l will be strongly typed to our view model

```
@model ServiceRequestViewModel
<div>
  <p> @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.ZipCode) <p>
  <p> @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.HomeService) <p>
</div>
```

Comment: My input's are located inside my _Layout.cshtml file, and I want to redirect to a different view, which actually uses a model.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to wrap your input fields in a form tag if you want to post the data to your controller action so your _Layout.cshtml code would need to change somewhat

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ServiceRequest","Home",FormMethod.Post,htmlAttributes:new{id="servicerequest-form"})){
    <div class="input-top">
        <a class="GoBtn" href=""><img src="~/Content/img/GOBtn.png" class="gobtn-position"></a>
        <input id="ZipCode" name="rvm.ZipCode" type="text" class="form-control input-position-2" placeholder="ZIP">
        <input id="ServiceName" name="rvm.ServiceName" type="text" class="form-control input-position-1" placeholder="What do you need done today?">
    </div>
}
```

then in the javascript you can do the post on the click event of your a tag.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.GoBtn').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var servicerequestForm = $("#servicerequest-form);
        servicerequestForm.submit();

    });
});
```

now in the implementation of the action it should look something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ServiceRequest(RequestViewModel rvm, HttpPostedFileBase image = null, HttpPostedFileBase video = null)
{
   return View(rvm);
}
```

Assuming that your new view is called "ServiceRequest.cshtml". There is alot more it seems to be going on in the controller and views which could affect the answer. for instance

```
       ViewBag.StateID = new SelectList(db.States, "StateID", "StateName");
```

That looks like a dropdown list that is being populated but that doesn't seem to be reflected in the _Layouts.cshtml that you gave. Also the posting of files together will model information will also give a different answer as how to handle that I hope I could have helped somewhat if at all?

Comment: This does the redirect, but then in my new view, the input fields corresponding to my model are empty, they don't get the text that I provide in the input fields in my Layout.

Comment: could you include the code you are using for your model and controller? it sounds like you are not setting the model for the new view

Comment: I did an edit, check it out. Please also note that initially, I'm in my _Layout.cshml file, and it doesn't have any model. Then, I want to redirect to a view that has RequestViewModel.

Comment: I think you have asked this question earlier it had more to do with the upload of a file

Comment: Why? The thing that I want to achieve is this. I have two input fields and one href in my _Layout.cshtml. If the user fills the input fields and presses the href attribute. I want the user to be navigated to a new view named ServiceRequest, which uses as a model RequestViewModel, and which has a few input fields. But when the user is redirected to that view, I want two of the input fields to be filled with the data that the user has previously filled from _Layout.cshtml, the other data should be empty. I don't want it to post or do something, just to redirect to view with data present.

Comment: Ok usually the a tag is for http get requests but it sounds like you need to do a post so I will update my answer accordingly